# View Raw JSON File in Browser

Tags: json, web-services, http

I'm writing an iOS app which will eventually retrieve data in JSON from a web service. However, before I get the web service running, I just want to test the app's ability to retrieve the JSON, so I thought I could simply upload a dummy JSON file (.json) to the root of a website I have hosted, point my browser to that file's URL and view (or at least download) the JSON.

Unfortunately, when I try to navigate to the JSON file's URL in my browser, I get the message

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

If I use the same URL in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) I get a different response:

> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

I realise I'm doing something stupid here and probably fundamentally misunderstanding something, but after quite a lot of Googling I don't know what! Everybody else with similar issues seems to reporting that they're prompted to download the JSON file rather than just seeing the data displayed in their browser, but I'm not even getting that. It'd be fine if I was! For what it's worth, I've verified the JSON itself in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: how does your code look like? can you post it/

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh there isn't any code, I'm not trying to do anything with code. I've just uploaded a JSON file to a web server and am trying to access it with a URL in a browser.